# How do I stream a file using werkzeug?

Tags: python, werkzeug

I want to stream a big file via [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/).
Currently my wsgi application looks like this:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from werkzeug.wsgi import ClosingIterator, wrap_file
import os

class Streamer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        filename = os.getcwd() + "/bigfile.xml"
        try:
            response = wrap_file(environ, open(filename) )
            return response
        except HTTPException, e:
            response = e
            return ClosingIterator(response(environ, start_response))
```

I'm not sure what I should do with the object returned by the [wrap_file](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wsgi/#werkzeug.wsgi.wrap_file) function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Haven't tried myself but I think following will work.

```
g = file(path_to_bigfile) # or any generator
return Response(g, direct_passthrough=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case one would additionally like to:
1. preserve the file name
2. issue download without page redirect

```
# file_name assumed to be known
# file_path assumed to be known
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
fh = file(file_path, 'rb')
return Response(fh,
                mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                headers=[
                    ('Content-Length', str(file_size)),
                    ('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"%s\"" % file_name),
                ],
                direct_passthrough=True)
```