# respond with csv file in flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I need to send db data in csv format:

```
def send_csv():
    mkdir_p('csv')    

    outfile = open('csv/output.csv', 'w')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)

    cursor = g.db.execute('Select * from my_table')

    outcsv.writerows(cursor)
    outfile.close()        

    return send_file('csv/output.csv', attachment_filename='output.csv')
```

But this gives following error during send_file:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted implicit sequence conversion but the response object is in direct passthrough mode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import below line in your script.

**from flask import send_from_directory**

Anyhow you are saving your csv in one folder and make that file serve using flask's inbuilt function called **send_from_directory**.

Change your return statement to this line, it will work.

**return send_from_directory('folder-path', file_name, as_attachment=True)**

For more details on **send_from_directory**, can go through the below link.

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/65747/flask.send_from_directory

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you should set direct_passthrough to false;
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/58917/flask.send_file

You can also send file without writing to fs;
[flask make_response with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318084/flask-make-response-with-large-files)