# How to avoid decoding when transferring a file with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to stream a file using Flask according to the answer given here: [How do I stream a file using werkzeug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166129/how-do-i-stream-a-file-using-werkzeug/5166423#5166423). The problem is I get the following error when werkzeug actually tries to stream the file:

```
ERROR:werkzeug:Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 319, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 310, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I am sending `mpac` files from my server and would like to avoid this decode/encode part entirely. Is there a way to avoid it in Flask? My code is below for reference

```
f = open(path_to_mpac)
resp = Response(f, status=200, direct_passthrough=True)
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream"
```

Comment: Try `open(path_to_mpac, 'rb')` instead (and maybe use `with open(...) as f:`

Comment: I added the `rb` option to my `open()` call and that got it working. Thanks!